# Notification on process affinity change

Tags: c, windows, affinity

Is it possible to be notified immediately when an external party changes your programs process affinity?  Without polling GetProcessAffinityMask().  For example if a user decides to change it via the task manager.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: This answer happened before the edit that added *"Without polling GetProcessAffinityMask()"* and did not specify the language of the check.

Yes, it's doable with a PowerShell for example. Set some base data once and make comparisons every once in a while.

You can get processes with `Get-Process` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7.1)) which returns `System.Diagnostics.Process` object ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-5.0)) with `Process.ProcessorAffinity` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.processoraffinity?view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_ProcessorAffinity)) property.

So getting the affinity would look like:

```
Get-Process PROCESS | Select-Object ProcessorAffinity
```

And with that - you can set your notifications (either mail, desktop or any other).

Comment: I actually wanted to know if it is possible to be notified immediately within my C++ program if someone has tampered with my processes affinity, ideally without polling it

Comment: *"Without polling GetProcessAffinityMask()."*

Comment: @IInspectable this was answered 9 hrs ago, before the edit with the _"Without polling GetProcessAffinityMask()."_ happened. Check please before minusing.

Comment: The original question asked for a *"notification"*. Polling is not a notification.

Comment: I understand notification as a mail, tooltip, message box or anything else that notifies me of a change. Note the sentence at the end of my answer: _"And with that - you can set your notifications (either mail, desktop or any other)."_

Comment: You do **not** get reliably notified using a strategy based on sampling. If changes happen between two sample points, you aren't observing them. Notifications, particularly on Windows, have a very distinct meaning: Events you can subscribe to, that don't exhibit the issues you get with sampling.